# Return String if object Existed Function in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a question about **Function** which Return String if object Existed in Django Rest Framework.

I want to set condition:
If FriendshipRequest model have `from_user = request.user` and `to_user=self.user`, this relationship_to_user fields will return: 'Existed', if not, print 'Not Existed'

Code in **Serializers:**

```
class UserDetailSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    relationship_to_user = SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            'id',
            'relationship_to_user',
        ]

    def get_relationship_to_user(self, instance):
      request = self.context.get('request')
      if FriendshipRequest.objects.filter(from_user=request.user, to_user=instance).exist():
          return 'Existed'
      else:
          return 'Not Existed'
```

This code is in **Viewset.py**

```
class UserDetailAPIView(RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserDetailSerializer
    lookup_field = 'username'

    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        to_user = self.get_object()
        serializer = UserDetailSerializer(to_user, context={'request': request})
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

**Issues Traceback:** get

```
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  58.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py" in dispatch
  489.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py" in handle_exception
  449.             self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py" in dispatch
  486.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\generics.py" in get
  210.         return self.retrieve(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\FeedGit\backend\api\authentication\views.py" in retrieve
  35.         return Response(serializer.data)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py" in data
  534.         ret = super(Serializer, self).data

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py" in data
  263.                 self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py" in to_representation
  501.                 ret[field.field_name] = field.to_representation(attribute)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\fields.py" in to_representation
  1755.         return method(value)

File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\FeedGit\backend\api\authentication\serializers.py" in get_relationship_to_user
  166.         if FriendshipRequest.objects.filter(from_user=request.user, to_user=instance).exist():

Exception Type: AttributeError at /api/v1/users/duongnuhabang/
Exception Value: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'exist'
```

Comment: so what's the problem?

Comment: Update Issues, @Ykh

Comment: `return ('Existed')` change to `return 'Existed'`

Comment: `friend_request_sent = FriendshipRequest.objects.filter(from_user=self.request.user, to_user=user)`  from where `user` comes from?

Comment: @ABDULNIYASPM How can I fix this, bro?

Comment: @Ykh Error: UserDetailSerializer' object has no attribute 'request'

Comment: @FeedGit Access request from `context`

Comment: thank you for remind,updated in answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

serializers.py

```
class UserDetailSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    relationship_to_user = SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            'id',
            'relationship_to_user',
        ]

    def get_relationship_to_user(self, instance):
        request = self.context.get('request')
        if FriendshipRequest.objects.filter(from_user=request.user, to_user=instance).exists():
            return 'Existed'
        else:
            return 'Not Existed'
```

views.py

```
class MyUser(RetrieveAPIView):
    serializer_class = UserDetailSerializer

    # you can override this method or not
    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        to_user = self.get_object()
        serializer = UserDetailSerializer(to_user, context={'request': request})
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: 'instance' is not defined in Views.py, bro

Comment: `instance` mean the `User` instance you want to serializer

Comment: `FriendshipRequest` has from_user and to_user,the instance in `serializer = UserDetailSerializer(instance, context={'request': request})` mean `to_user`,`from_user` is `request.user`.

Comment: In views.py, i use: `RetrieveAPIView`, serializer = UserDetailSerializer(instance, context={'request': request}) get this error: name 'instance' is not defined

Comment: add `instance = self.get_object()`

Comment: Is it import in views.py? When I import `instance = self.get_object()` in views.py. It get error: `self is not defined`

Comment: I updated my code above and get new error! I use lookup field `username`

Comment: it's `FriendshipRequest.objects.filter(from_user=request.user, to_user=instance).exists()` not   `FriendshipRequest.objects.filter(from_user=request.user, to_user=instance).exist()`, i miss a `s` character.

Comment: LOL. It's Success. Thank you very much! Vote best for ya :)

Comment: :) :) :) :) :) :)